# Variance of bivariate normal distribution plus normal distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, variance, covariance, bivariate

**Problem:**

$W = -27 + 0.3X + 0.45Y + E$

The pair $\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$ behaves like a bivariate normal with vector of averages $\begin{bmatrix} 156 \\ 86 \end{bmatrix}$ and covariance matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 16 & 23 \\ 23 & 164 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $E \sim N(0, 3^2)$.  What is the variance of W?

**My Answer:**

$var(W) = 0.3^2.var(x) + 0.45^2.var(y) + (2).(0.3).(0.45).cov(X,Y) + var(E)$
$var(W) = (0.3^2)(16) + (0.45^2)(164) + (2)(0.3)(0.45)(23) + 3^2$
$var(W) = 49.86$

**Question:**

Why textbook says $var(W) = 89.4916$ ?

Comment: Observe that since $20W$ is an *integral* linear combination of variables whose variances are all integers, the variance of $20W$ (which is $400=20^2$ times the variance of $W$) must also be an integer.  Thus, the answer *must* be a multiple of $1/400$--but $89.4916$ is not such a multiple.  There has to exist a typographical error somewhere--and it cannot possibly be in the variances, assuming they were intended to be integral. The likeliest conclusion is that the stated answer is wrong, but *why* it's wrong may be impossible to know.

Comment: Do you see erros in my approach?

Comment: @DavidDuarte Since 400×49.86=19944 is an integer, your answer passes the "whuber test". Looks right to me. (: